# Magento left navigation filter products by in stock or out of stock?

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento how can I filter products by stock in the navigation ?

Comment: I suggest you check the following topic of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070015/how-to-add-hide-out-of-stock-filter-layered-navigation-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

If you need only 2 filters (in stock and out of stock) you can use this stock filter module: https://github.com/tzyganu/stock-filter